# Kotlin's 'let' plus elvis, and accidental null return values

Tags: kotlin, idioms

I was surprised today to learn that this take on apparently idiomatic code fails:

```
class QuickTest {

    var nullableThing: Int? = 55

    var nullThing: Int? = null

    @Test
    fun `test let behaviour`() {
        nullableThing?.let {
            print("Nullable thing was non-null")
            nullThing?.apply { print("Never happens") }
        } ?: run {
            fail("This shouldn't have run")
        }
    }
}
```

It happens because, combined with implicit return, `nullThing?.apply{...}` passes null to the let, and therefore the elvis operator evaluates on null and runs the second block.

This is pretty horrible to detect. Do we have an appropriate alternative beyond conventional `if/else` without this pitfall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `also` instead of `let`. `also` will return `nullableThing`, whereas `let` will return whatever the lambda returns.

See this article: https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84 (point "3. Return this vs. other type").

Answer (score 4):

Your case is a candidate for `also` thematic. Compare two `block` actions:

```
fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T
fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R

nullableThing?.also {
    print("Nullable thing was non-null")
    nullThing?.apply { println("Never happens") }
} ?: run {
    fail("This shouldn't have run")
}
```

Another idiomatic way is to use `when` statement

```
when (nullableThing) {
    null ->
        print("Nullable thing was non-null")
        nullThing?.apply { println("Never happens") }
    else -> fail("This shouldn't have run")
}
```